Is my electrical rough-in code compliant?
Is this code compliant? 24.5 cu im box, 3 12-2 cables, internal clamp, 1 recepticle. Wires staples within 8" of box and every 4.5 ft.
I think it is, but it looks sloppy. Let me know if I am in violation. I don't care for the loop on the right side, but given that there is a clamp I have to enter from the bottom.

Here are some other options to make it less messy.
Option A
This can be done if I can drill holes lower than the box.
Option B

Are we evaluating the situation with or without the staples? You have two different cases here.

IMO nail plates are a good idea for any stud penetration regardless of depth. Not code, per se.

The most important thing you can do over and above code is make it easy to avoid your cables when hanging things on walls.  To that end:

People will assume there are cables directly above and below any switch or outlet.  Move that right hand wire to the same stud as the left hand one.
Keep your horizontal runs below the level of a chair rail.  Things don't get attached to the bottom half of walls much.  You already got that right.


It doesn't look sloppy to me.  You think it does because you watch youtube channels of electricians with youtube channels.   There's nothing wrong beautiful work but you don't have to do that, and remember that you can push/pull wire through finished walls and it would look much worse than this if you could see it.   Also your work will look better as you gain experience.
Whether you go in the top or bottom of a box should be determined by the result on the inside of the box ... making it neat and easy to maintain.   Whether you loop around the outside does not matter.  And in a small deep box like this it doesn't matter much inside either.   In a shallow multi-gang box you want to enter at the best possible place.

So are you suggesting I go with Option B? That's a lot of turns.

No.  I'm only suggesting the cable running down the right most stud should run down the one with the outlet instead.   If you were doing this fresh.  Not suggesting you change anything now.

I would do that but, I can't add anymore wires to the top of the outlet box. Its maxed out with the clamps. Since it is a deep box I can't continue past the box because the wire would be .5 inches away from the face of the stud

Looks fine to me.
The things you seem to be concerned about aren't really concerns. While neatness and material conservation are important, they aren't necessarily code violations. You really have just a few requirements:

Be sure all cables pass through the center of the framing (at least 1-1/2" from the face).

Fasten cables at least every 4 feet and within 12" of a box not having integrated clamps.

Don't bend the cable sharply.


Smooth and secure is the name of the game. After that it's fairly at your discretion. It does help to untwist (or unroll properly) so the cable never ends up all kinked and wiggly in the first place.

I updated the original picture as it did not show how how it currently looks. It is currently mock stapled at 6 inches from the box amd stapled every 4.5 ft.  The cables are also 1.5" from the face.  At th9s point I guess it is compliant?  Second question, is it code compliant to drill a hole below an outlet?

I think you're good based on the updated photo. You'd have to clarify your question. Do you mean is it ok to run wire through a wall down low? Sure. A better fix might be to raise the upper path to give yourself more room for bends and staples. Do what makes sense.
